# How can I set a TableView's titleForHeaderInSection and numberOfRowsInSection with an NSDictionary of NSArrays?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary with NSArrays of names, so naturally there are 26 arrays total. I'd like to set the `titleForHeaderInSection` (A, B, C, etc) with the keys of the arrays and the `numberOfRowsInSection` with the count of the arrays. I can get the count of each array by enumerating over them with a block, but how can I set these two options on my TableView based on the NSDictionary I have?  And is there any way to order the NSDictionary so the results are alphabetical?

Here's the NSDictionary I have:

```
@{
    @"A" :  
        @[@"Person One", @"Person Two", @"Person Three"],
    @"B" :
        @[@"Person One", @"Person Two", @"Person Three", @"Person Four"],
    @"C" :
        @[@"Person One", @"Person Two"],
}
// etc
```

Here's the NSLog of the NSDictionary: will the titles be unordered?

```
A -- 23
B -- 78
G => 27
U => 1
H => 57
V => 6
I => 1
// etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entries in a dictionary are not ordered. What you can do is create an array
of all the section titles and sort that alphabetically:

```
NSDictionary *dict = ...; // your dictionary
NSArray *sectionTitles = [[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Then the number of sections is

```
[sectionTitles count]
```

For a given section number, the title and number of rows can be computed as

```
NSString *title = sectionTitles[section];
NSUInteger numRows = [dict[sectionTitles[section]] count];
```

Finally, for a given index path, the corresponding item is

```
NSString *item = dict[sectionTitles[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row];
```